# Setting Customer's Billing Address through Stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm looking at the documentation for the Stripe API on how to create Customers.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=curl

But I'm not finding where I can actually update the customer's Billing Address.

I'm talking about the field that's in Customer -> Detail -> Billing information -> Address (in the dashboard), and it's the one that appears on the emailed receipt.

I can add it manually in the dashboard, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it with the API.

Best,
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it.

For some reason it's under the "shipping" property.

Comment: Billing and shipping addresses may be different because the credit card may be registered to an address and the goods are supposed to be shipped to another address. By any chance, can you show the nesting?